# mat-autocomplete fires displayFn when enter key is pressed in reactive form

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I created a custom reactive form control using `mat-autocomplete`.

When I use this component in a reactive form and I press the `enter` key from another form input field to submit the form, the autocomplete fires the `displayFn` and resets the current selected value, since the passed parameter is null. How can I prevent that the `mat-autocomplete` from reacting to enter key pressed, without having to listen to *each* keyboard key pressed?

I am using **@angular/material@11.1.2** and in older version of the same code I do not have this issue.

**parent FormGroup**

```
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
     placeName: [place.placeName],
     country: [{ name: place.countryName, code: place.countryCode }]
  });
```

**parent template**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save($event)" [formGroup]="formGroup" autocomplete="off">

  <mat-form-field class="two-third-space" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Name*</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="placeName" placeholder="Name*">
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- This is the custom form control -->
  <country-selector formControlName="country" [countryList]="countryList"></country-selector>

  <button type="submit" mat-button [disabled]="formGroup.invalid && formGroup.touched">Save</button>
</form>
```

**custom form control**

```
export class CountrySelectorComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  
  @Input()
  countryList: ICountry[] = [];

  @Input()
  appearance: MatFormFieldAppearance = 'standard';

  @Input()
  autocomplete: 'true' | 'false' = 'false';
  public filteredCountries: Observable<ICountry[]> | undefined;
  public formControlName = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.placeholder = this.placeholder || 'Country';
    this.initCountries();
  }

  initCountries() {
    this.filteredCountries = this.formControlName.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((country: string | ICountry) => (country && typeof country === 'object' ? country.name : country)),
      map((name: string) => (name ? this.filter(name) : this.countryList.slice()))
    );
  }

  filter(val: string): ICountry[] {
    // Regex to match with the first letters of the country name with the passed value.
    return this.countryList.filter((country) => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(country.name));
  }

  resetCountrySelection() {
    this.formControlName.setValue(null);
    this.propagateChange(null);
  }

  // When the 'enter' key is pressed on anotehr field of the form, the autocomplete fires
  // this method passing a null parameter, that resets the displayed value. 
  displayFn = (country: ICountry): any => {
    if (typeof country === 'string') {
      return country;
    } else if (typeof country === 'object') {
      return country?.name ? country.name : '';
    }
  }

  writeValue(country: ICountry): void {
    if (country) {
      this.formControlName.setValue(country);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, country: ICountry) {
    if (event.source.selected) {
      this.propagateChange(country);
    }
  }

  propagateChange = (value: any) => {};

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
}
```

**custom form control template**

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance" class="form-field">
  <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
  <input type="text" 
         class="input-search" matInput
         [formControl]="formControlName"
         [matAutocomplete]="panel"
         [autocomplete]="autocomplete" />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #panel="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selected($event, country)" *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries | async"
    [value]="country">
    <div class="selector-elements">
      <span>
        {{ country.name }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

[image]

Comment: Try return at the end of `displayFn`, `country ||  this.formControlName.value`

Comment: formControlName is undefined when `displayFn` is triggered. While debugging, if I analyse the `this` object, it refers to the `mat-autocomplete` and not the component, hence all the variables and parameters are null

Comment: You may need to use arrow function  `displayFn = (option: any) =>` or in html `.bind(this)`

Comment: Nope. I updated the code accordingly, but it is still null (updated my question with a screenshot)

Comment: It looks like `typeof null === 'object'` is true.
So logic in `if (typeof country === 'object')` condition comes into the play. Is it expected?

Comment: That's a side effect, that anyway falls back to an empty string (hence it is ok, here). The problem is that after the enter key is pressed, I cannot fetch the already selected value of the mat-autocomplete, and the passed object is always null, plus if I attempt to use the `this` object, this is also undefined and does not point to my component as expected. It is like the inner autocomplete gets triggered with its inner scope (even using `bind(this)`)